# Insert images from Directory using Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert images from a folder based on what is written in a cell

Example

Cell A1 has the word "ABC001"

I want cell B1 to insert the image from a directory - image name = "ABC001.JPG"

I have found some VBA code that does this for me, but this only works on one cell.
i would like it to work on the entire column

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myPict As Picture
Dim PictureLoc As String

If Target.Address = Range("A2").Address Then

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete

PictureLoc = "\\ca-sbs-01\t\Shared\ExcelImages\" & Range("A2").Value & ".jpg"

With Range("B2")
    Set myPict = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PictureLoc)
    RowHeight = myPict.Height

    myPict.Top = .Top
    myPict.Left = .Left
    myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend you using `Dir(Path)` to get the exact filename and some If to handle an error that would happen if it wasn't there. As for doing for the whole column you could use a loop to get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are after this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myPict As Picture
Dim PictureLoc As String

    On Error GoTo EH
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 1 Then

        'Pictures.Delete

        PictureLoc = "\\ca-sbs-01\t\Shared\ExcelImages\" & Target.Value2 & ".jpg"


        With Target.Offset(, 1)
            Set myPict = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PictureLoc)
            .RowHeight = myPict.Height
            myPict.Top = .Top
            myPict.Left = .Left
            myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With

    End If
EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```